# Swift - How can I get the current time in seconds?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, timezone, nsdate

A user posts a comment in a different timezone and another user views the comment in different timezone. The time should be the same when converted back to the users timezone on their device.

Here's what I am trying but getting an "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". The error is happening in my distance time variable when its trying to subtract "time". I printed time before it executed and its saying "nil". Any help please?

```
import UIKit
```

class EventCommentCell: UITableViewCell {

```
var obj : EventCommentObj!

@IBOutlet var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var commentMessage: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var time: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func setData(){



    profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
    profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false


    profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.125, green: 0.757, blue: 0.569, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.height/2
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true

    print("The Image URL : \(obj.profileImage)")


    ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(obj.profileImage, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
        self.profileImage.image  = image
    })

    let message = "\(obj.username) \n\(obj.comment)"



    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message as String)

    let range: NSRange = (message as NSString).rangeOfString(obj.username as String)
    let range1: NSRange = (message as NSString).rangeOfString(obj.comment as String)
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(commentMessage.font!.pointSize)

    attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: range)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.125, green: 0.757, blue: 0.569, alpha: 1.0), range: range)

    commentMessage.attributedText = attributedString

    time.text = getCreationTimeInt(obj.created_on)

}

func getCreationTimeInt(dateString : String) -> String{

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()


    let time = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)?.timeIntervalSince1970

    let distanceTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - time!

    let stringTime = returnDistanceTime(distanceTime)

    print("**** The time \(stringTime)", terminator: "")

    return stringTime

}

func returnDistanceTime(distanceTime : Double) -> String{

    var stringTime = ""

    if (distanceTime < 0) {
        stringTime = "0s"


    }else{
        if(distanceTime < 60){
            stringTime = "\(Int(distanceTime))s"


        }else{
            if(distanceTime < 3600){

                stringTime = "\(Int(distanceTime/60))m"

            }else{

                if(distanceTime < 3600*24){
                    stringTime = "\(Int(distanceTime/3600))h"

                }else{

                    if(distanceTime < 3600*24*7) {

                        stringTime = "\(Int(distanceTime/3600/24))d"

                    }else{
                        stringTime = "\(Int(distanceTime/3600/24/7))w"

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return stringTime
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you storing the date?  Typically you just store the date either as an NSDate (if supported) or a string that includes the timezone and then you can easily convert that back to an NSDate.  You shouldn't need to muck about with seconds from GMT

Comment: You only get that error when you use "!" to force unwrap. Therefore `time` is nil. My guess is that `dateString` does not conform to your format, so `dateFromString` fails.

Comment: If I change my timezone to UTC on my computer and then run my code again in the simulator it will not work just fine and print the time. It just does not convert it to GMT.

Comment: What does `dateString` look like?

Comment: It would help if you explained what you're trying to do. Are you trying to take a local time and convert it to a UTC string for storing, and then redisplay later in the local timezone? Regardless, you're setting `timeZone` twice which is probably wrong, and it's very unlikely you actually want `systemTimeZone` (`localTimeZone` is more likely).

Comment: Example of what I am trying to do: If a user posts a comment in Calgary and Calgary being a one hour difference to Vancouver. The comment being view in Vancouver should read as "1 min ago" not "1 hour ago". Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Please show the time string you are storing/reading. If this string doesn't include the timezone, change it so that it does.  You can then simply convert this to an NSDate and display it in the local timezone.  All of the time conversion will be done for you

Comment: Please see my code above.

Comment: I assume that `obj.created_on` is an NSDate. If you subtract this from the current date (ie. `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`), you will get the same value everywhere in the world. There should be no reason to convert anything to a string. NSDate is independent of any time zone.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack overflow. I plugged what you had into a Playground and it worked perfectly. Here is what I have:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa


func returnDistanceTime(distanceTime: NSTimeInterval) -> String{

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}



func getCreationTimeInt(dateString : String) -> String{

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    let time = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)?.timeIntervalSince1970

    let distanceTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - time!

    let stringTime = returnDistanceTime(distanceTime)

    print("**** The time \(stringTime)", terminator: "")

    return stringTime

}



getCreationTimeInt("2016-03-01 12:12:12")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What's your timezone?

Comment: Central Time Zone - USA

Comment: Just to confirm, your dateString is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" correct?  Just like: "2016-03-01 12:12:12"

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the let time = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)?.timeIntervalSince1970 line. Then step into the function, to see where it breaks.

Comment: distanceTime NSTimeInterval -9550.6053409576416 -9550.6053409576416

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from above from Aaron but in Swift 5

```
func returnDistanceTime(distanceTime: TimeInterval) -> String{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
}



func getCreationTimeInt(dateString : String) -> String{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale

    let time = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)?.timeIntervalSince1970

    let distanceTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - time!

    let stringTime = returnDistanceTime(distanceTime: distanceTime)

    print("**** The time \(stringTime)", terminator: "")

    return stringTime

}
```